# Перенаправление в htaccess статика на статику

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Есть ссылка test.com/vsem_privet_kak_dela_2018 надо чтобы по ней открывалась страница test.com/video/2/audio/4 (точнее сервак обрабатывал именно её), но пользователь видел первую ссылку, а на экране были обработанный серваком данные.
Я сделал вот так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^vsem_privet_kak_dela_2018$ /video/2/audio/4 [L]
```

реакции нет, вот так тоже нет:

```
RewriteRule ^vsem_privet_kak_dela_2018/?$ /video/2/audio/4/
```

Сайт делал не я, перед моим условием есть еще вот такие:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(test\.com)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule \.(bz2|js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|html|cur|xml|txt|php|swf|flv|htc|ttf|eot|woff)$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Может они как то влияют, к сожалению очень слаб в этом вопросе((

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteRule ^vsem_privet_kak_dela_2018$ /video/2/audio/4/
```

Или так, для общего случая со солэшом на конце в url:

```
RewriteRule ^vsem_privet_kak_dela_2018[/]*$ /video/2/audio/4/
```

Comment: Я именно так и написал, только ключ L в конце был и слэш написал вот так /?$ . Но увы(((, наверное надо думать над условием.

Comment: @SergeyPavlov так покажите (отредактируйте вопрос), что у вас было написано.